# about : asm (.desc xxx 0x10)

Tags: ios, debugging, assembly

Any string written into this magic global variable ("**crashreporter_info**") will show up in that section of the crash log. Why?

```
const char *__crashreporter_info__ = NULL;
asm(".desc _crashreporter_info, 0x10");

#define MAAssert(expression, ...) \
    do { \
        if(!(expression)) { \
            NSString *__MAAssert_temp_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Assertion failure: %s in %s on line %s:%d. %@", #expression, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat: @"" __VA_ARGS__]]; \
            NSLog(@"%@", __MAAssert_temp_string); \
            __crashreporter_info__ = [__MAAssert_temp_string UTF8String]; \
            abort(); \
        } \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gas/gas_7.html#SEC77) is what `.desc` mean

Comment: Archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20200503054247/http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gas/gas_7.html#SEC77